# Extract text from PDF file with password protection

Tags: ghostscript

I am trying to extract text from specific pages of PDF files protect with password.

I am try to use `pdf2txt %my_file.pdf%` but I could not make the command understand the password input or page as argument.

By the example in https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=691125, I am trying `pdf2txt -sPDFPassword="a" h.pdf`.

Answer (score 1):

Not clear which of hundreds of pdf2txt or pdftotext apps your using so check if it passes a GS password like that (most would not)

as you link the command would be dependant on GS itself getting
**gs -sPDFPassword=password [...... other options](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm) h.pdf**

so my version is windowsX32 thus path and .exe different but the result would be similar in x64 etc. `gswin32c -sPDFPassword="a" h.pdf`

[image]

for your commented use on windows it could be like :-

`>gswin32c -q -dSAFER -sDEVICE=txtwrite -dTextFormat=3 -o - -sPDFPassword=a -f h.pdf`

> ```
>           Hello world!
> ```

much simpler would be use the alternative poppler/xpf pdftotext commands  typically
`pdftotext -layout -opw a h.pdf out.txt & type out.txt`

> ```
>                 Hello world!
> ```
>
> ♀

or for console

```
>pdftotext -nopgbrk -fixed 10 -opw a h.pdf -
               Hello world!

>
```

Comment: `pdftotext` appear to work but it just to not output the string in the terminal. Which is need for my application (not write a file). So I am using the `pdf2txt` from the ghostscript package, a super set of `pdf2ascii` of same package.

Answer (score 0):

`gs -sDEVICE=txtwrite -sOutputFile=- -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH to-be-processed.pdf` accept the parameter `-sPDFPassword="a"` before the file name.